# Is there any way to prevent Spring boot from adding suffix for client-id when connecting to the Kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using spring boot 2.5.4 with the related version of spring-kafka.
Spring boot adds a suffix to the configurated client-id.
For example, if you set this configuration in the application.properties:
spring.kafka.client-id=siavash

you see that it use siavash-0 to communicate with the broker(s), which is also mentioned in the documentation: [search word "suffix" in this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.3/reference/html/)

is there any way to prevent spring boot from adding this suffix? or disable it?

Comment: try setting the group id or application id - it is not clear which api you are using/how you are communicating to the cluster (producer/consumer/kstreams)

Comment: Don't use a concurrent container?

Comment: @OneCricketeer how?

Comment: For example, use something other than ConcurrentKafkaListener... We can't see your code to know what you're actually using, though

Comment: See `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.setAlwaysClientIdSuffix(boolean)`.

Answer (score 1):

On the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` ...

```java
    /**
     * Set to false to suppress adding a suffix to the child container's client.id when
     * the concurrency is only 1.
     * @param alwaysClientIdSuffix false to suppress, true (default) to include.
     * @since 2.2.14
     */
    public void setAlwaysClientIdSuffix(boolean alwaysClientIdSuffix) {
        this.alwaysClientIdSuffix = alwaysClientIdSuffix;
    }
```

```java
@Component
class Customizer {

    Customizer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory) {
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> container.setAlwaysClientIdSuffix(false));
    }

}
```